# LaTeX-internal definition of \thesection

Tags: numbering, counters, chngcntr

I am using a redefinition of the equation-numbering as in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\counterwithin*{equation}{chapter}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\section{First section}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that `\thesection` gives `"current chapter number"."current section number"`. Respectively all minor structure level numbers have their major level numbers before their own number. In fact that is not a problem for me; this MWE achieves exactly the behaviour I want to have. I just want to understand why LaTeX does this. Is there any advantage in it (except of shortening this redefinition command)? And what are the disadvantages?

P.S.: How can I call then the counter for just my current section?

Comment: `\arabic{section}` is the current section.

Comment: It is done that way so that if you change the print format of the chapter (say to roman instead of arabic numerals) then all lower counters use the new form for their chapter number prefix, with no redefinition required.

Comment: @David Carlisle This sounds actually quite useful. I did not think of that before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last question how to use the section counter in conjunction with the equation counter:

`\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}`

will print the equation number with the section number as prefix only, not the full nine yards with `chapter.section.X`.

Now the more generic answer about the `\thefoo` - like commands.

In principle such commands like `\thesection` are recursively defined!

Depending on the real setup (with `chngcntr`'s `\counterwithin` etc. commands) and the underlying class the structure is usually

```
\def\thefooleveltwo{\thefoolevelone.\arabic{fooleveltwo}}
\def\thefoolevelthree{\thefooleveltwo.\arabic{foolevelthree}}
```

In this case, `foolevelone` would be `chapter`, `fooleveltwo` is `section` and `foolevelthree` will be `subsection` etc.

The precise setup will differ most likely in the usage of `\arabic`, `\alph`, `\Alph`, `\roman`,`\Roman` mainly.

In order to get the current section number, just use `\arabic{section}` or `\number\value{section}`

The advantage of this numbering scheme is a definition mapping which equation/section/figure etc. belongs to which chapter or structure level.

The disadvantage is that you can't use something like

`\setcounter{section}{\thesection}`

in most cases, because `\thesection` may have non-numbers (like periods or roman figures) in its output.

Some more details -- from `latex.ltx`

`\newcounter{foo}` will call `\@definecounter` effectively, here is its definition:

```
\def\@definecounter#1{\expandafter\newcount\csname c@#1\endcsname
     \setcounter{#1}\z@
     \global\expandafter\let\csname cl@#1\endcsname\@empty
     \@addtoreset{#1}{@ckpt}%
     \global\expandafter\let\csname p@#1\endcsname\@empty
     \expandafter
     \gdef\csname the#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
          {\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
```

At the end the `\gdef\....` will define `\thefoo` being a command that prints the counter value with arabic numbers -- this is the default setup, so right from the start, any `\the...` (as long as related to counters) will print arabic numbers.

The final output behaviour is defined by the class (in most cases), like here in `article.cls`

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {section}
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
```

As can be seen by the row of `\renewcommand{\the...}` macros, the commands are recursively defined, where `\@arabic\c@foo` is the internal representation of `\arabic{foo}` actual (`\c@foo` the 'real' counter macro name)

Comment: Ok, this sounds quite logic. And if I would like to number my equations in scrreprt only with the section numbers (for whatever reason) how could I achieve that? Is it simply possible to use `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}` to do this manually?

Comment: @Enno: Yes, exactly that way